# mysql backup preserving relationships

Tags: backup, mysql, database-backups

I would like to know how to backup my data from 2 separate tables (CATEGORIES and SUBCATEGORIES, where SUBCATEGORIES belong to a CATEGORY) in such a way that I can restore the relationship at a later time. I am not sure if `mysqldump --opt db_name` would suffice.

Example:

Categories:

```
| ID | name
-----------
| 1  | Audio
| 9  | Video
```

Subcategories:

```
| ID | category_id | name
-------------------------
| 1  | 1           | Guitar
| 2  | 1           | Piano
| 3  | 9           | Video Camera
```

Thanks

Comment: As victor hugo says, the relation is represented by ordinary table data and will be dumped just as anything else. A related scenario that is a lot more complicated would be if you had to export the data to merge them with another db of the same strcuture, i. e. you couldn't keep the IDs. Then you should either use UUIDs (these could be mapped to plain ints for efficiency), or create a custom program.

Answer (score 5):

***mysqldump* is sufficient**

It will generate the SQL code necessary to rebuild your database and as the relationships are not special data (just *logical coincidences* between tables) it's enough to backup a database. Even by using mysqldump without the *--opt* param it will add indexes definitions so the contraints will remain

Answer (score 1):

the  mysqldump  default add the  create table  command and it save the relation.